# Can Internet Explorer bind events to absolute positioned elements?

Tags: jquery, events, internet-explorer, bind

Can Internet Explorer bind events to absolute positioned elements ?

I can't bind a "click" to an element that is overlapping another.

Have tried loads of different ways, here a few tests that don't work in IE:

```
//version 1:
$(".classHolder").click(function(){ alert( $(this).html() );  });

//version 2:
$(".classHolder").each(function(){ $(this).click(function(){ alert( $(this).html() );  }); });

//version 3:
$("#id3").click(function(){ alert( $(this).html() ); });

//version 4:
$("#id3").click(function(){ alert( $(this).html() ); });
$("#id3").trigger("click");


// in all trials I tested with and without:
// $("img").unbind();
// $("div").unbind();
// just to make sure no "ghost" events were bind into the elements but no success.


<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#id3").click(function(){ alert( $(this).html() ); });
   $("#id3").trigger("click");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="id1" style="position:relative;">
<img id="id2" src="http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" style=";z-index:-1;"/>
<div id="id3" class="classHolder" style="position:absolute;border:2px solid red;left:0px;top:0px;width:70px;height:70px;z-index:1002;">G</div>
<div id="id4" class="classHolder" style="position:absolute;border:2px solid red;left:210px;top:0px;width:25px;height:70px;z-index:1001;">L</div>
asd asdf asdfg
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In mycase position absolute + filter: [ or -ms-filer ] was problem remove solve issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:
added

```
"background-color:#FFFFFF;"
```

to the element style.
and used the wacky function:

```
function setOpacity(obj,value){
  obj.style.opacity=value/10;
  obj.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+value*10+')';
}
```

and finally, when binding the evento to the element:

```
   $("div.classHolder").each(function(){
      $(this).bind("click",function(e){ alert($(this).html()); }); 
      setOpacity(this,0);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. Resolved with css.

Added this "hack" in my element style definition :

```
background-color:#ffffff;
filter: alpha(opacity=1);
opacity: 0.01;
```

Tested in firefox 4, IE 7 and latest safari

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is necessarily your problem or not, but have you tried changing your "type" attribute to "text/javascript" instead of "application/javascript"? Again, this may have 0 effect. But then again, IE is quirky.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:
1) As someone else pointed out, IE is ignoring the script without the type set to "text/javascript"
2) When the element is absolute positioned, the click events only fire if the mouse is over "content" in the abs div. In this case, the text content like the G letter. You can set a background-color to allow clicks anywhere in the div. Alternatively, you can set a very large font-size and just put a &nbsp; in the element with overflow:hidden to allow it to be transparent, but still process clicks on the whole element.

Here is a modified version of your example:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#id3").click(function(){ 
        alert( $(this).html() ); 
        }); 

   //$("#id3").trigger("click"); 
}); 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="id1" style="position:relative;"> 
<img id="id2" src="http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" style=";z-index:-1;"/> 
<div id="id3" class="classHolder" style="position:absolute;font-size:9000px;overflow:hidden;background-color:transparent;border:2px solid red;left:0px;top:0px;width:70px;height:70px;z-index:1002;">&nbsp;</div> 
<div id="id4" class="classHolder" style="position:absolute;border:2px solid red;left:210px;top:0px;width:25px;height:70px;z-index:1001;">&nbsp;</div> 
asd asdf asdfg 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Well said, and I quote:
"2) When the element is absolute positioned, the click events only fire if the mouse is over "content" in the abs div."
Thanks